# How to set timelimit for OsilCouenneSolver, CoinOptServices.jl package

Tags: julia, solver, julia-jump

I am using Julia, JuMP to solve a NLMIP problem. I am using Couenne solver through CoinOptServices.jl package

```
using JuMP
using CoinOptServices
```

I would like to set a timeout for the solver, something like

```
mdl = Model( solver=OsilCouenneSolver(time_limit=20)  )
```

and, if possible, an absolute or relative optimality tolerance.

I wasn't able to find a way.

Any help, particularly on the timeout, would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Francesco

Comment: You may get faster responses if you post these questions either on the [julia-opt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-opt) mailing list or as a [github issue](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/CoinOptServices.jl/issues) on CoinOptServices. I'm not sure if the author of CoinOptServices follows stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow the suggestion. Best, Francesco